# Using CPU memory to store GPU output

Tags: python, gpu, sparse-matrix, eigenvector, cupy

I was wondering whether it could be possible to tell cupy to store the output of some calculation (carried on the GPU) directly on the CPU memory. I am currently trying to use `cupy.scipy.sparse.eigsh` to diagonalize a large sparse matrix, and unfortunately I get memory issues as the eigenstates of the matrix are not sparse and occupy too much space. Is there any possible fix for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transfers between CPU and GPU memory, to and fro, are obviously possible otherwise GPGPUs would be of no use.

Comment: Intuitevely it would make sense something similar to what I need should be possible. However I am not an expert and dont know enough. Furthermore, the problem I am having is that its not a matter of transfering data from GPU to CPU. Rather, I would need CuPy to store the output of eigsh directly on the CPU memory (the program keeps crashing because it is uncapable of saving the eigenvectors due to their size)

Comment: I doubt that you could modify the scipy code to let the GPU use the CPU RAM for mass storage, if that even makes sense. Better look if you can find "block diagonalization" methods (which is not the same as "diagonalization of block diagonal matrices".

Comment: You can't address system memory from the GPU

Answer (score 1):

There are `SciPy` and `CuPy` to do this. Scipy runs on CPU and copy runs on GPU. As you use Cupy right now, you can try Scipy:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html

Comment: Scipy would definitely be good alternative if the size of my sparse array was reasonable. Unfortunately that's not the case (as of now I am dealing with sparse arrays of size 1e9 x 1e9, which would not be a problem if the eigenvectors of this would also be sparse) and using the CPU would use far too long.